# Inserting JSON.Stringified data into MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, mongodb

```
var obj = {};
obj.url = hostNames[i];
obj.statusCode = res.statusCode;
obj.headers = res.headers;

db.collection.save(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

I am currently attempting to request a HTTP response via Node.js, and then parsing that output into a MongoDB with `JSON.stringify` (a method that transforms things into JSON document format). For some reason, I am getting some weird output in MongoDB, it goes something like this:

```
> db.scrape.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51472849650593014a3c20da"), "0" : "{", "1" : "\n", "2" : " ", "3" : " ", "4" : "\"", "5" : "u", "6" : "r", "7" : "l", "8" :
```

What I think it is doing is that it is interpreting each char as a new variable. What did I do wrong in my code?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here: why are you trying to store a JSON-string, and not a document itself? As Mongo expects you to provide a _document_, it does the only more-o-less sensible thing to the string provided - parses it as an array. You should have at least store it like... `db.collection.save({res: JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)});`. But, frankly speaking, you're trying to do the Mongo's work here: why not format this object when you output it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am thinking, it would just be more convenient to have JSON.stringify() to format the import. What would you do in my case? Keep in mind I have three objects `url`, `statusCode`, and `headers` per "website". The `url` is the primary key for each "website" response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

why stringify the obj?   the API expects a javascript object.

Just do:

```
db.collection.save(obj);
```

Comment: It has been deprecated. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the output of JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)?
I guess this would return the expected result.

There are two possible reasons for this error:
The way of storing the document is wrong or
the way the document is retrieved is wrong

At http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/ (mongodb getting-started) there is no mention of converting the documents to json before calling insert or whatever.

Have you tried storing it like
db.collection.save({'content': JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)});?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a Meteor project. "response" is a string that contains data in json format. "save" method didn't work. I created a new document simply by:

```
 obj = JSON.parse(response);
 db.collection.insert(obj);
```